# jQuery Validate - Hide display validation error messages / show custom errors

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Validate, but I really don't want to have any error messages whatsoever. Rather, I need to have red boxes around offending inputs/selects/etc. These red boxes were a piece of cake to add, but I still cannot remove error messages themselves. How do I disable them altogether?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use a custom error placement function (see the plugin's [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options)) that doesn't append the error message to anything.

```
$('#form').validate({
  errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
    return true;
  }
});
```

Or you could put the error messages elsewhere on the page - say in a DIV at the top of the page.

Comment: Thanks, found this answer while having the same problem :)

Comment: @tvanfosson, It it OK to use CSS like this: `label.error {display:none !important;}`

Comment: @RainLover That wouldn't override any styles set directly on the element. I'd have to look to see how the plugin normally does the display.  If it's entirely class-based it would work but if it uses show/hide then it wouldn't. It would also force you into a global solution (assuming a single site-wide style sheet).

Answer (score 10):

You can override the `showErrors` function:

```
jQuery('form').validate({
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        // Do nothing here
    },
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    rules: {
        email: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        email: {
            required: 'The email is required'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Won't that also eliminate highlighting the element?

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, it actually does.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I do it.  Just put `$.validator.messages.required = '';` before your call to initialise validate() i.e.:

```
$.validator.messages.required = '';
$('#formData').validate({});`
```

This will make it show the styles on the inputs, but no message labels!

Comment: You will still need `label.error {display:none !important;} ` since the empty boxes take up space.