# jQuery manual validate without showing error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I am using jQuery validation in ASP.NET MVC 3. Is there a possibility to check if an input is valid without showing the error messages next to the actual input?

I have tried:

```
$("#myForm").validate().element("#myInput1"); // this shows the error message only for the myInput1 element

$('#myForm').valid(); // this shows the error messages for all fields.
```

I am not trying to suppress the errors showing forever, I just want to check if the fields are valid by using the validation created on server. That one is subject to change so I do not want to have two validation definitions (one on client and one on server). Thanks!

Later Edit:

```
var a = $('#myForm').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error,element) {
                       return true;
                    }
}).element("#myInput1");
alert(a);
```

This also shows the errors.

Comment: use `remote` option to use server to validate a field... see docs

Comment: I agree with @charlietfl. However check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578007/jquery-validate-hide-display-validation-error-messages-show-custom-errors
you can add a custom handler here.

Comment: @charlietfl: I don't want to do useless request to the server to check for a client validation.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico: I tried the solution posted there, but it still shows the error messages when I validate.

Comment: how is it `useless`? Sending to server saves user a step and a page refresh if field invalid. As for `errorPlacement` you must not be checking element properly for error not to display. SHow code

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, not useless, sorry, but resource-consuming. I want to keep the functionality on client-side. I have updated my answer with the code you requested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Overriding errorPlacement just returning true will mean all errors are not displayed.  You can use the [check](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js#L528) method on the validator object to quietly check a field.  It takes a DOM element as the only argument, so with your code example you would have

```
$('#myForm').validate().check($('#myInput1')[0])
```