# How to highlight validation jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd love some help over here since I'm a rookie when it comes to jQuery.

I have this code right here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#subscribe").validate({
            debug: false,
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: "*",
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('wp-content/themes/abc/process.php', $("#subscribe").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
});
```

Now, what im trying to do is to replace the message: * , with a highlight of the input field. So instead of showing the message * right after my e-mail input field, i'd like to add a class to my e-mail input field. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose jQuery adds 'error' class to input and highlights it itself. Doesn't it? http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/ If you just want not to show the message - the answer can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578007/jquery-validate-hide-display-validation-error-messages-show-custom-errors

Comment: Jquery adds .error class via validation, so you could just modify the .error class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [victor k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1589961/victor-k) and [Cory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2155529/cory) mentioned, jQuery validate adds a `.error` class to the element being validated if it doesn't pass the validation rules. It also adds a default message. If you want to remove the message and highlight the input field, you can set the message to the empty string and highlight the input field with CSS. Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#subscribe").validate({
    debug: false,
    rules: {
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      }
    },
    messages: {
      email: "",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $.post('wp-content/themes/abc/process.php', $("#subscribe").serialize(), function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  #email.error {
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="subscribe">
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
</form>
```